Split a String Into the Max Number of Unique Substrings: O(n^2) solution explanation (Leetcode 1593)
I found an $O(n^2)$ accepted submission to LeetCode 1593, and I don't understand why it works.
I have included the problem statement, my understanding of what the $O(n^2)$ code does, the submitted code with my comments, and my effort in understanding the submitted code.
Problem Statement

Split a String Into the Max Number of Unique Substrings
Given a string s, return the maximum number of unique substrings that the given string can be split into.
You can split string s into any list of non-empty substrings, where the concatenation of the substrings forms the original string. However, you must split the substrings such that all of them are unique.
A substring is a contiguous sequence of characters within a string.

My Understanding of the Accepted Submission
Let's define the Naive Algorithm as follows:
Starting from the leftmost character, keep adding characters to the current substring until it becomes unique, then cut the current substring and add it to the unique substrings. If there are remaining characters at the end of the input string, concatenate them to the last unique substring.
Naive Algorithm Pseudocode
S = empty set
current_substring = "" 
for c in input:
    current_substring += c
    if current_substring not in S:
        # cut the current substring and add it to the substrings set
        add current_substring to S
        current_substring = ""
add the remaining characters (current substring) to the last added substring.

What the Submitted Code Does:

For each i, divide the input into two parts: input[:i] and input[i:].
Perform the naive algorithm on input[:i], continue (without resetting S) with input[i:], but ensure there is no cut immediately after i. Count the number of substrings and update the maximum.

Invert the input and repeat step 1.

Perform the naive algorithm on the inverted input and update the maximum if necessary.

Return the maximum.


Accepted Submission
Here is the accepted code:
class Solution:
    def maxUniqueSplit(self, s: str) -> int:
        # m is the max number of unique substrings found 
        m = 0 
        # d keeps track of the unique substrings
        d = {} 

        # Step 1
        for i in range(len(s)):
            # Dividing at i
            a = s[i]

            # Naive algorithm on the left side of i
            b = ""
            for j in range(0, i):
                b += s[j]
                if b not in d:
                    d[b] = 1
                    b = ""

            # Naive algorithm on the right side of i. 
            # b += a ensures there is no cut after the ith character
            b = ""
            b += a
            for j in range(i + 1, len(s)):
                b += s[j]
                if b not in d:
                    d[b] = 1
                    b = ""

            # Count the number of substrings and update max
            m = max(m, len(d))
            d = {}

        # Step 2: Same as step 1 on the reversed string
        d = {}
        a = ""
        for i in range(len(s) - 1, -1, -1):
            a = s[i]
            b = ""
            for j in range(len(s) - 1, i, -1):
                b += s[j]
                if b not in d:
                    d[b] = 1
                    b = ""
            b = ""
            b += a
            for j in range(i - 1, -1, -1):
                b += s[j]
                if b not in d:
                    d[b] = 1
                    b = ""
            m = max(m, len(d))
            d = {}
        
        # Step 3: Naive algorithm on the reversed input
        d = {}
        a = ""
        for i in range(len(s) - 1, -1, -1):
            a += s[i]
            if a not in d:
                d[a] = 1
                a = ""

        m = max(m, len(d))       

        # Step 4: Return max
        return m

My Effort and Questions
Here is a summary of my efforts in understanding the algorithm:
A. I can show two things about the naive algorithm:

The naive algorithm always cuts the input string into unique substrings.1
The naive algorithm is not always optimal.

For example, consider the input abaxaxr:

Naive algorithm output: [a, b, ax, axr]
Better outputs: [a, b, axa, x, r] or [a, ba, xa, x, r]

B. I explored three approaches to solving the problem that could explain the code, but I wasn't successful:

Find the optimal solution given there is no cut between the $i^{th}$ and $(i+1)^{th}$ characters.
Find the optimal solution given there must be a cut before the $i^{th}$ character.
Look at the first cut that differs in the optimal and naive solutions.

Can you explain why this code works if it is correct? If not, could you provide an example input where the solution fails?

1: We show that concatenating the remaining characters to the last unique substring doesn't affect its uniqueness. Let $\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n\}$ be the substrings found by the naive algorithm and let $R$ be the remaining characters. Since none of $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_{n-1}$ equal $X_n$, the concatenation $X_nR$ cannot exist in $\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_{n-1}\}$, because the naive algorithm would have found the unique substring at $X_n$. More generally, for each $i$ and $j$ where $i \neq j$, if $X_i$ is a prefix of $X_j$, then $i < j$.

"Here are 50 lines of uncommented code with one letter variable names. Explain it to me." is not a good way to ask a question.

@Nathaniel Thanks for the feedback. I updated the question, hopefully it is better now.

Yes! Thanks for your efforts!

I see no reason why it should work, and in fact it doesn't: it returns 4 for aabaaabaa, missing a ab aaa b aa. (I found this by testing it on random strings against a brute-force solution.)
Incidentally, its runtime is $O(n^3)$, not $O(n^2)$, since operations on the substrings take $O(n)$ time.

Thank you! Did you have an approach or intuition when testing random strings?
I spent some time trying different inputs and couldn't find any input that didn't work.

@R.Javid I guessed that if there was any failure case there would be one with two symbols. Then I just automated it. It worked on hundreds of strings before failing on one. In hindsight I should have just tested all binary strings by length, since the failing case was so short. Having just done that, aabaaabaa is the only failing case of length 9 or less.
